# 'Secret sauce' in MacOS X private APIs for Java - request for further detail

Tags: java, macos

On his blog Scott Kovatch writes:

> Without getting into too much detail, typing ‘java MyAWTCode’ from a Terminal window violates a whole lot of assumptions about what an application is on Mac OS X, and needs a lot of cooperation between the AWT and the Process Manager to sort it out.
>       http://skovatch.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/secret-smoke-screens/

Out of curiosity - what assumptions are violated? Surely this is just a candidate for an API call with callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I can elaborate on that a bit.

The Process Manager starts with the assumption that all applications that present a UI on Mac OS X are bundled, are packaged in a folder named Application.app, binary in Contents/MacOS/Application, and most importantly, have an Info.plist to get things like the name of the application that will be shown in the application menu. When you run a Java application from the command line (Swing or SWT) there is no Info.plist, so we had to create a CFDictionary to be passed off to a private SPI that would register the application, give it a proper name in the Dock -- as opposed to just 'java' -- and could be force-quit.

Even then, it's not perfect, because the Dock also assumes it can store an alias to the bundled application when you right-click and choose Keep In Dock, but since there isn't one that fails silently. There's no way to store a shortcut or command line to start the application like Windows can.

The SWT just calls TransformProcessType, which is a start but is nowhere near sufficient to turn a Java application into a full UI application. For doing pure SWT testing and development it's enough to get you going. When you create an Eclipse RCP-based application for deployment you end up with a bundled application with the Eclipse launcher, and plugins and features, and you're ready to go.

Of course, if you go the extra mile and package your Java application into a bundle, this is all moot, but the vast majority of developers coming from other platforms don't bother and just want to run an executable JAR file or even a folder of class files with a shell script.

Comment: So this is seriously what all the fuss about 'private MacOS APIs' in the Mac version of Java was all about? That's nuts.

Comment: It was more than that. I believe there were also some Java2D things that could only be done with private APIs, but it's been a long time since I saw that code. But, I agree that blaming private Mac OS X APIs is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what he had in mind, but I guess a big difference is the file structure: a normal MacOS X application is a bundle with the structure NameOfTheApp.app/Contents/MacOS/NameOfTheApp , and specific files in the Contents directory. When we use the terminal with a "java" command, the JVM has to create a "virtual" application specific to the Java code, and handle all the MacOS events for it. Also, when you open an application twice in the Finder, it simply activates the application the second time, while you need to launch separate applications every time you use "java MyAWTCode".